# Java generic Comparator unchecked warning

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

I wrote a help method to combine multiple comparators to one:

```
public static <T> Comparator<T> createComparatorChain( final Comparator<T>... comparators )
{
    return new Comparator<T>()
    {
        public int compare( T lhs, T rhs )
        {
            for( Comparator<T> comparator : comparators )
            {
                int order = comparator.compare( lhs, rhs );
                if( order != 0 )
                {
                    return order;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }   
    };
}
```

But if i use this method then i got a unchecked warning:

```
Collections.<File>sort( list, ComparatorUtils.<File>createComparatorChain( BY_FILE_DIRECTORY, BY_FILE_NAME ) );
```

Type safety: A generic array of Comparator is created for a varargs parameter.

I something in my generic syntax wrong? Can anyone help me.

Comment: Could you show us how you use this comparator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I something in my generic syntax wrong?

No, it's just another wart on how Java generics are implemented. Basically, arrays and generic types don't play nicely together. See the [Java generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ104) for more details.

In this particular case, I'd build the chain not from an array, but from several comparators which are linked together - each knowing about the one with higher priority and the current lower priority one. That avoids the array. Each comparator just asks its parent to perform the comparison, and returns the result directly if it's non-zero, or performs its own comparison and returns that otherwise. The "top" comparator doesn't have a parent, so just performs its own comparison.

Fortunately you don't even need to write this yourself - you can use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) either with [`ComparisonChain`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html) or [`Ordering.compound`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#compound%28java.util.Comparator%29). Note that there's an overload of `compound` which is *like* your array version, but takes an `Iterable<? extends Comparator<? super T>>` parameter - which *is* safe.

Answer (score 1):

This is the classic issue with generics and varargs. Long story short, it's because varargs is really syntactic sugar for an array. e.g. in this case, `comparators` has type `Comparator<T>[]`. And at the call site, the compiler creates an array of the right type. Except, of course, as you may know, Java does not allow you to do `new Comparator<File>[]`, so the compiler does `new Comparator<?>[]` instead and gives you a warning.

It is important to know that the "unsafeness" only occurs if you depend on the actual array type of `comparators`. If you only need to iterate through its elements (as your method is doing), then it's still perfectly safe. To indicate that your function is safe in this way, if you're using Java 7+, add a `@SafeVarargs` annotation to your method, and the warning will stop.